# Can I compile Visual Studio 2013 DLL's in Visual Studio 2015?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I just upgraded to Visual Studio 2015, but I have a DLL that is used by some clients that was compiled with Visual Studio 2013.

Is there anyway for me to compile this DLL in 2015, without needing them to download the 2015 redistributable?

Comment: which redistributable?

Comment: They have 2013 x86 redistributable installed already (all of them), but I don't want them to have to install 2015 x86 redistributable when I compile again using Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: You need VS2013 as well, you can use the ToolSet option in a VS2015 project to get a 2013 compatible flavor of the DLL.  If you designed your DLL interface *very* carefully or the client doesn't use C++ at all then you can build your DLL with /MT instead of /MD.  That however doesn't come to a good end very often.

Comment: you can modify the target framework and platform toolset to be the same as 2013. see this for more details: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ff770576.aspx

Comment: Thank you guys. I am installing Visual Studio 2013 Community now. I didn't know about the 2015 toolset option...